# Disposing of IDisposable Without Reference

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, garbage-collection, idisposable

Sometimes an instance of a class that implements `Dispose()` is used without actually retaining any reference to the instance.

What should be done regarding garbage collection in this case?

Example:

```
MsgBox(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.website.com"))
```

`WebClient` implements `Dispose()`.

Please feel free to rename the subject as you see fit.

Comment: What is the problem to rewrite the code to have reference on `IDisposable` object?

Comment: That is my question. Should I just use the code as is, or is it a bad idea and I should rewrite it? What happens in the code I provided? Is the `WebClient` being properly disposed of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you should refactor the code so that disposal happens. That is exceedingly easy thanks to the `Using` statement.

I do now know why `WebClient` needs to be disposed. In simple use cases it does not hold onto any resource as far as I can tell.

This issue has nothing to do with the GC. This object will be cleaned up like any other object when the GC finds it unreferenced.

Comment: So, the idea is to get resources back ASAP, and in my code snippet that does not happen until the Garbage Collector gets around to disposing of the object. Correct?

Comment: Yes, where "disposing" should be "deletion" in your statement. Note, that if you want to reclaim resources quickly you need to open the message box after calling Dispose. This, however, is probably unnecessary considering that no resources are being held in all cases that I know of.

Comment: Update: WebClient does not even override Dispose. Dsipose does nothing meaningful. This is a waste of time, just put it in a Using statement.

Comment: `WebClient` was just an example I had handy, but this is more of a general question. So when GC "deletes" the object, or a `using` block exits, all resources are reclaimed that instance, is that correct?

Comment: Dispose and GC clean up all unmanaged resources (by convention). In addition the GC deletes the memory which, here, is tiny (dozens of bytes).

Comment: So, when I create an instance in this manner, what is the proper term for it? Anonymous?

Comment: No term for that. It's a new expression I guess.

Comment: @mcu - Just to be very clear - the GC **never** calls `.Dispose()`. You **must** explicitly call it to clean up the resources.

Comment: @usr - Just to be very clear - the GC **never** calls `.Dispose()`. You **must** explicitly call it to clean up the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Only in very rare cases should properly-written code ever allow all references to a resource-holding object be abandoned without `Dispose` having been called on it first.  In addition to problems resulting from delayed cleanup, careless handling of `IDisposable` objects can also in some cases result in *early* cleanup.

For example, suppose one has a class `Widget` which uses some sort of native handle to a `Widget`, and it has a method

```
void Woozle()
{
  NativeWidget.Woozle(myWidget));
}
```

If the very last thing which is done with a `Widget` before abandonment is to call `Woozle`, the GC may notice that it fetches the value of `myWidget`, none of the fields of that `Widget` can ever be accessed again and thus nobody should notice if it disappears.  Because garbage-collection is an asynchronous process, that could happen *even while the `Woozle` method is running*.  If `Widget` has a destructor or `Finalize` method that releases the `myWidget` resource, the results could be disastrous.

If, by contrast, the `Widget` reference had been kept around for purpose of calling `Dispose` on it, and `Dispose` does either `GC.SuppressFinalize` or `GC.KeepAlive`, then there's no possibility of the finalizer running until after the call to `Woozle` is complete.